# (Brackets IDE) html5 reference javascript files

Tags: javascript, html, reference

I have been following a tutorial on videogame making with the Brackets IDE (using HTML5 and JavasScript). I was asked to divide the code in different files and reference them in the main one, but it is not working, it does not recognize the variables declared in the other files.

The code is the following:

[Current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqeEk.jpg)

Comment: I tried to paste the code i have written but it woul be taken as real code and because of that it could not appear as text the part I am asking about (the reference making)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a sort of namespacing for your code. So still if it is split in different files it will refer to a master source.

```
// script 1
(function(global){
    var framework = global.framework = global.framework || {};

   framework.UtilityOne = function(){};
   framework.collectionOne = f[];

})(this);


 // script 2
(function(global){
    var framework = global.framework = global.framework || {};

   framework.UtilityTwo = function(){};
   // check framework reddiness
   // because you don't know when all files are loaded 
   //and i which order they loaded
   framework.ready(function(){
      framework.collectionOne.push('something');
   });

})(this);
```